# GLEW is just and extension library or it contains OpenGL ES 2.0 implementation as well?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-es-2.0, glew

GLEW is just and extension library or it contains OpenGL ES 2.0 implementation as well?

> The OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library (GLEW) is a cross-platform
>   open-source C/C++ extension loading library. GLEW provides efficient
>   run-time mechanisms for determining which OpenGL extensions are
>   supported on the target platform. OpenGL core and extension
>   functionality is exposed in a single header file.

I am confused as I find the following in `glew.h`:

```
#define glLinkProgram GLEW_GET_FUN(__glewLinkProgram)
```

where `__glewLinkProgram` is

```
GLEW_FUN_EXPORT PFNGLLINKPROGRAMPROC __glewLinkProgram;
```

where `PFNGLLINKPROGRAMPROC` is obtained from a `lib` or a `dll`, I guess. I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: GLEW just makes accessing (some of) the functions provided in the .SO/.DLL provided by our graphics-card manufacturer easier. It does not contain openGL or openGL ES.

Comment: So OpenGL ES is being installed with graphics card driver?

Comment: I imagine so. My only contact with it has been with the RaspberryPi and Android platforms - neither of which support the 'full-fat' OpenGL. The wikipedia page for OpenGL ES indicates that it's also supported by Intel HD Graphics found in _some_ chipsets, also by _some of_ the Nvidia implementations available to desktops running Windows/Linux. Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first line of your quote states what GLEW is:

> The OpenGL Extension Wrangler Library (GLEW) is a ... **extension loading library**.

It loads OpenGL extension functions from the OpenGL implementation (typically provided by GPU drivers). It doesn't implement them themselves.

Those `PFN...` typedefs are provided by `glext.h` and are function pointer types. GLEW simply defines some variables to hold the function pointers, and to load them using using the `wglGetProcAddress` or `glXGetProcAddress` functions.

Answer (score 4):

The official version of glew does not support OpenGL ES at all, only desktop OpenGL. However, some unofficial adaptations / forks of glew have sprung up, such as Linaro's [glew-es](https://launchpad.net/linaro-graphics-misc/+download), that do support OpenGL ES.

Comment: GLFW? This question is about GLEW.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Indeed. Amended.