# Typedef Redefinition with OpenGL - GL vs Khronos

Tags: c++, build, opengl-es, glsl

I'm running into build errors while trying to build and execute an OpenGL project from GitHub: https://github.com/djbozkosz/Light-Propagation-Volumes

I loaded the project into QT, and when building it gives me the following 4 errors:

```
Light-Propagation-Volumes/src/headers/openGLTypes.h:39: error: typedef redefinition with different types ('int64' (aka 'long long') vs 'khronos_int64_t' (aka 'long'))
Light-Propagation-Volumes/src/headers/openGLTypes.h:45: error: typedef redefinition with different types ('uint64' (aka 'unsigned long long') vs 'khronos_uint64_t' (aka 'unsigned long'))
Light-Propagation-Volumes/src/headers/openGLTypes.h:53: error: typedef redefinition with different types ('int32' (aka 'int') vs 'khronos_intptr_t' (aka 'long'))
Light-Propagation-Volumes/src/headers/openGLTypes.h:54: error: typedef redefinition with different types ('int32' (aka 'int') vs 'khronos_ssize_t' (aka 'long'))
```

The previous declarations apparently are in glext.h:

```
typedef khronos_uint64_t GLuint64;
typedef khronos_int64_t GLint64;
typedef khronos_ssize_t GLsizeiptr;
typedef khronos_intptr_t GLintptr;
```

which is never (explicitly) included in the project. I read about some incompatibility between OpenGLES [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37775194/typedef-redefinition-with-different-types-emscripten-sdl2opengl), but don't really know what to make of it. The only header file I include in `openGLTypes.h` is `#include <GL/glx.h>`. When changing that to `glew.h`, I get around 2000 build errors and unresolved filenames, etc.

Comment: All github-hosted projects have their own bug tracking and forums, so why do you think you'll be more likely to get help on some general programming site like Stackoverflow, instead of the project's own forums and bugtracker?

Comment: just comment out the lines in `openGLTypes.h` I would say. If the gl headers define the GL types, there's no reason to re-define them in a non-portable way (as the author of that repo did)

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: because this isn't a project, but a compiler-/linker related issue.

Comment: @PeterT thanks for the suggestion, I tried that before, and it results in 1773 errors, all more or less similar to "invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘const GLubyte*’ {aka ‘const unsigned char*’} [-fpermissive]"

Comment: did you try adding `-fpermissive` to the compiler flags (and remove the `-pedantic`)?

Comment: What does "a compiler/linker related issue" mean? All compilation or linking failures are, by definition, reported by the compiler or linker. It could very well be a portability issue with some particular version of some library you're using. This seems to be the case, I recently had to do something similar to update my code for OpenSSL 3.0. The project's users and maintainers of that project will be far more likely to know exactly what the problem is, than anyone here who's unlikely to be familiar with that code.

Comment: @PeterT, thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately, it doesnt change anything. Still throws the same typedef errors.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik the project has last been updated 4 years ago and up until then has been maintained by a single person. I added a Github issue there as well, but believe that the probability of getting useful help here on SO is higher.

Comment: Well, that, pretty much, makes it far more likely that it's bit rot. The library hasn't been updated to reflect the changes to libc and system header files. It's unlikely that anything can be done about it, short of forking that project and bringing it up to date. That's the only likely answer to come from SO.

Comment: @masterBroesel if I uncomment the typedefs in `openGLTypes.h` and add `-fpermissive`, remove `-pedantic`, it compiles just fine for me. Obviously still throws the warnings, but doesn't fail to compile

Comment: It's pretty obviously bit-rot, the `openGLTypes.h` header defines `GLsizeiptr` to be `int32`. I don't think in 2022 assuming a pointer is 32-bits is a safe bet.

Comment: "comment out" is what I meant, not "uncomment"

Comment: Indeed, @PeterT, I pulled the project anew and tried your suggestions, and it compiles (with some slight modifying the QT source code) and lets me view the GUI. It's far from running, as there are lots of unresolved files, etc, but I hope that this is fixable. Thanks!